# jQuery and if statments and radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

The script I'm attempting to get to work is designed to hide a button in the event that user is on a certain section of the page. The problem is that the .hide() isn't being fired, I believe it has to do with the if statement, just not quite sure.

```
$(function () {
    var sndReminderBtn = $('.sendreminderBtn');
    var resultSelection = $('.resultsSelector');



    if (resultSelection.is(':checked')) {
        sndReminderBtn.hide();
        alert("Button is hidden");

    } else {
        sndReminderBtn.show();
        alert("button is NOT hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: << is designed to hide a button **in the event that user is on a certain section** of the page>> There is nothing like that in your code

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to need to fire this on an event, rather than checking for it when the page is loaded - as your current code looks absolutely fine. Either that, or you've got an element class the wrong name, or multiple elements given the same class.

Comment: @roasted You are correct, there is ALOT going on in the full page code as it's apart of a whole site, which is pulling from a fair bit of different classes as the site is built using a MVC framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't attach the handler to an event, it won't work. Also, the code can be way shorter:

```
$(function () {
    $('.resultsSelector').on('change', function () {
        $('.sendreminderBtn').toggle($(this).is(":not(:checked)"));
    });
});
```

Comment: This does the job! Perfect thanks. I've been trying to teach myself jQuery for a little while now, so still learning the in's and outs. Appreciate it.

Comment: No problems. Once you get used to it, you'll see how easier things can be. :)

Comment: Please remember to mark this answer as the solution if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the way in that you are verifyng if the requestSelection is checked

Change:

```
if(resultSelection.is(':checked')){
```

By:

```
if(resultSelection.attr('checked')){
```

Or if you are using jquery 1.6+

```
if(resultSelection.prop('checked')){
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a listener when the page is loaded then trigger your function

```
$(function () {
     $('.sendreminderBtn').click(showHide); 
});

function showHide(){
    var sndReminderBtn = $('.sendreminderBtn');
    var resultSelection = $('.resultsSelector');
    if (resultSelection.is(':checked')) {
        sndReminderBtn.hide();
        alert("Button is hidden");

    } else {
        sndReminderBtn.show();
        alert("button is NOT hidden");
    }
}
```